# Support of paramref attribute with see tag

Tags: c#, language-lawyer

In a doxygen question (unfortunately quite old already) it is stated that `<see paramref="..."> isn't handled at all` (see: https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/issues/5111). This is correct.

I looked in the most recent C# definition I could find: "C# Language
Specification, 5th Edition / December 2017" but here I could not find any reference to a `paramref` attribute, I did find a `paramref` (and `typeref`) tag but this is different.

Question:

- is `paramref` a possible attribute for the `see` tag (and probably the `seealso` tag) and if so where can I find a reference?

(Note I'm not a C# programmer hence the question).

Comment: I wouldn't expect C# specifications to handle such commenting meta-language. Is that already the case for other XML-comment-elements (don't know how to call them) ? Isn't it rather an *implementation detail* ? Or something unrelated to the C# compiler at all (more an IDE thing) ?

Comment: You're correct - there is no `paramref` attribute; there is only a `paramref` tag.